# Building Ogre fails on Osx Lion

Tags: macos, ogre, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to install rviz on my mac book.
I installed all the dependencies, in particular wxWidgets-python and py26-wxpython by using the variant +gtk (I had done it because I needed it for compiling PCL, wihch require wxgtk. I found out that wxWidgets-python +gtk is good too).
I also installed the nvidia-cg-toolkit by using the installer download from [here](http://developer.nvidia.com/cg-toolkit-download).

Now, when I try to build Ogre it returns me the following error:

```
macbook-di-luca:ogre luca$ rosmake --rosdep-install --pre-clean 
[ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['ogre']                                                                                             
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['ogre']                                                                                                     
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/Users/luca/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110825-111203                                                          
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['ogre'] to:
['ogre']                                                                                                  
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .             
Failed to find rosdep nvidia-cg for package ogre on OS:macports version:macports
WARNING: Rosdeps [u'nvidia-cg'] could not be resolved
rosdep executing this script:
{{{
set -o errexit
#No packages to install
}}}
[ rosmake ] rosdep successfully installed all system dependencies                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> ogre [ make clean ]                                                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< ogre [PASS] [ 54.18 seconds ]                                                                                           
[ rosmake ] Starting >>> tools/rospack                                                                                                           
[ rosmake ] Finished <<< tools/rospack                                                                                                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> ogre [ make ]                                                                                                           
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesre: 928.2 sec ]                                                                                [ 1 Active 0/1 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/RTShaderSystem/OgreShaderMaterialSerializerListener.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/RTShaderSystem/OgreShaderProgramProcessor.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/RTShaderSystem/OgreShaderCGProgramProcessor.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/RTShaderSystem/OgreShaderCGProgramWriter.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/RTShaderSystem/OgreShaderGLSLProgramProcessor.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/RTShaderSystem/OgreShaderGLSLProgramWriter.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/RTShaderSystem/OgreShaderProgramWriterManager.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/RTShaderSystem/OgreShaderHLSLProgramProcessor.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/RTShaderSystem/OgreShaderHLSLProgramWriter.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/ExampleApplication.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/ExampleFrameListener.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/ExampleLoadingBar.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/FileSystemLayer.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/OgreStaticPluginLoader.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/Sample.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/SampleContext.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/SamplePlugin.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/SdkCameraMan.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/SdkSample.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/include/OGRE/SdkTrays.h
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/bin/OgreXMLConverter
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/bin/OgreMeshUpgrader
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/CMake/FindOIS.cmake
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/CMake/FindOGRE.cmake
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/CMake/FindPkgMacros.cmake
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/CMake/PreprocessorUtils.cmake
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/CMake/OgreConfigTargets.cmake
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/CMake/OgreGetVersion.cmake
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/CMake/OgreFindFrameworks.cmake
  -- Installing: /Users/luca/Software/ros/diamondback/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/CMake/FindIOKit.cmake
  Showing first 200 notices only
  
  
  ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
  
  rm -rf ogre/lib/Ogre.framework
  mv ogre/lib/RelWithDebInfo/Ogre.framework ogre/lib
  touch installed_osx
  BUILD FAILED: Plugin_CgProgramManager.so not created.  Is nvidia-cg-toolkit installed?
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package ogre written to:                                                               [ 1 Active 0/1 Complete ]
[ rosmake ]    /Users/luca/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110825-111203/ogre/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< ogre [FAIL] [ 928.19 seconds ]                                                                                          
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package ogre. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                          
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                             
[ rosmake ] Cleaned 1 packages.                                                                                                                  
[ rosmake ] Built 1 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                    
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                          
[ rosmake ] /Users/luca/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110825-111203
```

First of all, I don't understand if ogre is successfully built or not. One of the last lines says `** BUILD SUCCEEDED **` and it seems that the failure was during the creation of a plugin.

Second, how can I install the `nvidia-cg-toolkit` in such a way that Ros will recognize it?

Thanks,
Luca

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11012/building-ogre-fails-on-osx-lion/) by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2011-08-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The check for the Cg plugin generated by OGRE is broken for OS X. Here is a patch:

```
        Index: Makefile
===================================================================
--- Makefile    (revision 37811)
+++ Makefile    (working copy)
@@ -71,11 +76,19 @@
    else \
      make ogre/lib/pkgconfig/OGRE.pc; \
    fi
-   @if test ! -f ogre/lib/OGRE/Plugin_CgProgramManager.so; then \
-          echo "BUILD FAILED: Plugin_CgProgramManager.so not created.  Is nvidia-cg-toolkit installed correctly?"; \
-          exit 1; \
-        fi
+   @if test `uname` = Darwin ; then \
+       if test ! -f ogre/lib/Plugin_CgProgramManager.dylib; then \
+           echo "BUILD FAILED: Plugin_CgProgramManager.dylib not created.   Is nvidia-cg-toolkit installed correctly?"; \
+           exit 1; \
+       fi \
+   else \
+       if test ! -f ogre/lib/OGRE/Plugin_CgProgramManager.so; then \
+           echo "BUILD FAILED: Plugin_CgProgramManager.so not created.  Is nvidia-cg-toolkit installed correctly?"; \
+           exit 1; \
+       fi \
+   fi

+
 ogre/lib/pkgconfig/OGRE.pc: $(SOURCE_DIR)/CMakeLists.txt $(SOURCE_DIR)
         # building OGRE
    mkdir -p $(ROOT)/$(SOURCE_DIR)/build;
```

I made a ticket here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5132

EDIT: Had to fix a syntax error on the patch.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2011-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2